# Can I run data cables in the same cabinet as a service panel?

Tags: electrical-panel

If the power panels inside my home are all enclosed (no exposed live wiring anywhere), am I allowed to route my data cables and coax to a router and (data distribution hardware) housed in the same room and wood back panel in which my power panel resides or do I need to house it separately?

It is situated in a door sized cavity of 2 feet deep with a normal door to close it. There is about 4sqft of open space on the wood back planes on the bottom.

I don't want to do work that an inspector will reject. I read all the codes and the relevant posts on this site, but want an honest opinion, preferably qualified. [This is what I read](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/42030/is-there-any-code-for-running-ethernet-cable-through-attics?newreg=756330969a3e4fcc940e4adc69a06b6fhttps://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/42030/is-there-any-code-for-running-ethernet-cable-through-attics?newreg=756330969a3e4fcc940e4adc69a06b6f).

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. Please ask just one question per post. You may post several questions in separate posts.

Answer (score 1):

In the same decorative wooden cabinet, yes.

In the same conduit, raceway, gutter or service panel, no, unless the entire low voltage circuit, and the involved appliances, are all built to mains wiring standard...

So for instance the Ethernet cable could not run in a power conduit, come out to an RJ14, and go to a computer in the normal way with a commodity ethernet cable, since neither the RJ14 jack nor cable is rated for mains power.

The problem they are concerned with is any random wires in the raceway shorting together, so suddenly there's 240V on your ethernet cable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is fine. Some things to watch out for beyond the post you linked to:

- Maintain the open space in front of any panels. IOW, don't put anything in front of the panel.
- Don't attached anything to the existing wires, panels or conduit. For example, don't use zip ties to hold your CAT6 cables to a conduit.
- Don't use the same holes through studs, headers and wallboard as the current carrying wires. Drill your own holes away from the existing holes.

Answer (score 0):

According to CEI: No, but you can run wires in same conduits if data or antenna wires have an insulation rated for, at least, same as mains voltage. (223V)